# Using Grid and Proxy to read and save data with only one url (ExtJS 4)

Tags: php, ajax, json, extjs, grid

I didn't understand well the idea behind of proxies in ExtJS. Can I use simple functions with them in order to read and save data using only one url? Such as when I want to read data: `users.read()` and when I want save the new and edited fields of a grid: `users.save()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use functions as `users.save()` and `users.read()` and this functions will use urls which you provide for these methods in Proxy.

```
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                api: {
                    create:{
                        url: '/users/create',
                        method: 'POST'                        
                    },
                    read: {
                        url: '/users/read',
                        method: 'POST'
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: '/users/update',
                        method: 'POST'
                    },                  
                    destroy: {
                        url: '/users/delete',
                        method: 'POST'
                    }
                }
            }),
```

or

```
proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    method: 'GET',
    prettyUrls: false,
    url: 'local/default.php',
    api: {
        // all actions except the following will use above url
        create  : 'local/new.php',
        update  : 'local/update.php'
    }
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I could answer your question any better than if you were to read the following article.

[Sencha > Learn > The Data Package](http://www.sencha.com/learn/the-data-package/)